# Fourier sine transform of $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1-x^2}{4x}\ln\vert\frac{1+x}{1-x}\vert$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, bessel-functions

Show that
$$
\int_0^{\infty} kF(k)\sin(ka)\,dk = \frac{\pi}{2}aG(a)
$$
where
$$
F(x) = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1-x^2}{4x}\ln\vert\frac{1+x}{1-x}\vert
$$
and
$$
G(x) = \frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{x^4}
$$

EDIT: The source can be found [here](http://folk.uio.no/yurig/Nanotechnology/GMR/RKKY.pdf). One should notice that the function $F(x)$ is not continuous at $x=1$.

EDIT2: The integral below may be of some help.
$$
\ln\vert\frac{a+x}{a-x}\vert = 2\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin at\sin xt}{t}\,dt 
$$

EDIT3: Here is a mathematica code of my question:

> F[x_] := (1/2 + (1 - x^2)/(4 x)*Log[Abs[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]])*x*Sin[a*x];
>
> Integrate[F[x], {x, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> a > 0]

The result is:

> ([Pi] (-a Cos[a] + Sin[a]))/(2 a^3)

EDIT4: By virtue of Bessel function $J_{\frac{1}{2}}(z)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z}}\sin(z)$, the integral identity turns to be
$$
\int_0^{\infty} k^{\frac{3}{2}}F(k)J_{\frac{1}{2}}(ka)\,dk = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}a}G(a)
$$
In this occasion, some refs are useful:

(1) [Lin](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/731/art%253A10.1007%252Fs11139-013-9529-4.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Farticle%2F10.1007%2Fs11139-013-9529-4&token2=exp=1435588819~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F731%2Fart%25253A10.1007%25252Fs11139-013-9529-4.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Farticle%252F10.1007%252Fs11139-013-9529-4*~hmac=b3170319dd8c2935e994a8d53eb46e44bd2597a0c06a92ae8c97ef66d47cb794) Q.G.: Inﬁnite integrals involving Bessel functions by an improved approach of contour integration and the residue theorem.

(2) [Lucas](http://educ.jmu.edu/~lucassk/Papers/BESS.pdf) S.K.: Evaluating inﬁnite integrals involving Bessel functions of arbitrary order.

Comment: Hi, please see my edit of my question, where you can find the source of the problem.

Comment: Hello,you link can't open it,can you told us which book or which paper?

Comment: i think this may be done by using a suitable integral representation of the logarithmic term. Maybe one that is obtained by a Frullani like integral. thinking about it...

Comment: @math110: Sorry for the disable link, I have corrected it. In fact, this integral relates to the well-known phenomenon in solid-state theory, the so-called RKKY interaction.

Comment: you can further simplify parts of the integral by differentiating w.r.t. a

Comment: Yes, thank you. Thank you for your both hints. I am just working on it.

Comment: Please note also that on some point you will have to interpret some integrals in a distributional sense because they are not defined otherwise

Comment: hmm thinking about it, the constant term in $F(k)$ gives me some headache. It turns out to be proportional to $\delta'(a)$ but i don't know where it will be canceled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral can be written as
\begin{align}
I&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty} k\sin(ka)\left[1+\frac{1-k^2}{2k}\ln\left|\frac{1+k}{1-k}\right|\right]\,dk\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty} \left( 1-k^2 \right)\sin(ka)\left[\frac k{1-k^2}+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{1+k}{1-k}\right|\right]\,dk\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left( 1+\frac{d^2}{da^2} \right)\int_0^{\infty} \sin(ka)\left[\frac k{1-k^2}+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{1+k}{1-k}\right|\right]\,dk
\end{align}
Now, recognizing that
\begin{equation}
\frac k{1-k^2}+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{1+k}{1-k}\right|=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dk}\left( k\ln\left|\frac{1+k}{1-k}\right| -2\right)
\end{equation} 
The function $g(k)= k\ln\left|\frac{1+k}{1-k}\right| -2$ is is such that $g'(k)$ is integrable, $g(k)\sim 2k^{-2}/3$ for $k\to\infty$ and $g(k)\sim -2$ for $k\to 0$.
It comes
\begin{align}
I&=\frac{1}{4}\left( 1+\frac{d^2}{da^2} \right)\int_0^{\infty} \sin(ka)\frac{d}{dk}\left( k\ln\left|\frac{1+k}{1-k}\right| -2\right)\,dk\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}\left( 1+\frac{d^2}{da^2} \right)a\int_0^{\infty} \cos(ka)\left[k\ln\left|\frac{1+k}{1-k}\right| -2\right]\,dk\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}\left( 1+\frac{d^2}{da^2} \right)a\frac{d}{da}\int_0^{\infty} \sin(ka)\left[\ln\left|\frac{1+k}{1-k}\right|-\frac{2}{k}\right] \,dk
\end{align} 
We know (GR 17.33.35) that
\begin{equation}
\ln\left|\frac{1+k}{1-k}\right|=2\int_0^\infty\sin t\sin kt \frac{dt}{t}
\end{equation} 
and 
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{2\sin(ka)}{k}dk=\pi
\end{equation} 
thus
\begin{equation}
I=-\frac{1}{2}\left( 1+\frac{d^2}{da^2} \right)a\frac{d}{da}\left[\int_0^{\infty} \sin(ka)\,dk\int_0^\infty\sin t\sin kt \frac{dt}{t}-\pi\right] 
\end{equation}
The contribution of the constant term in the bracket vanishes as it does not depend on $a$. The double integral is the sine transform of the sine transform of $\sin t/t$. Finally,
\begin{align}
I&=-\frac{\pi}{4}\left( 1+\frac{d^2}{da^2} \right)a\frac{d}{da}\left( \frac{\sin a}{a} \right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin a -a\cos a}{a^3}
\end{align}